# How to give validations for a PrimaryKeyRelatedField serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I add validations like required=true to the primarykeyrelated serializer?

models.py

```
class WorkLocation(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longtitude = models.FloatField()
```

serializers.py

```
class WorkLocationField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    queryset = WorkLocation.objects.all()

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if type(data) == dict:
            location, created = WorkLocation.objects.get_or_create(**data)
            data = location.pk
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

class JobPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    work_location = WorkLocationField()

    class Meta:
        model = JobPost
        fields = "__all__"
```

A part of my data looks like:

```
"hourly_pay": 10,
    "yearly_pay": 120,
    "work_location": {
        "city": "kottayam",
        "latitude": 0.00001,
        "longtitude": 0.0012
    },
    "Benefit": [
        1
    ],
```

I need validations for the nested JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your `JobPostSerializer`, it seems like your `JobPost` model has a `OneToOne` relationship with `WorkLocation`.This means that your `models.py` looks like this:

```
class WorkLocation(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longtitude = models.FloatField()

class JobPost(models.Model):
    work_location = models.OneToOneField(WorkLocation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

To provide validation for work_location field on `JobPostSerializer`, you can create `WorkLocationSerializer` as follows:

```
class WorklocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkLocation
        fields = "__all__"

    # field level validation
    def validate_city(self, value):
        # value validation
        return value

    def validate(self, data):
        # data validation
        return data

class JobPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = JobPost
        fields = "__all__"

    work_location = WorkLocationSerializer()
```

This way you can perform all of your validations inside the `WorkLocationSerializer` and when added as a field on another serializer the nested validation works.

Comment: By uising modelserializer , I can only add pk value to work location. I want to add a dictionary. The work location data is created inside the jobpost Json.

Comment: What do you mean you can only add pk to work location ? we are not using a primary key related field, we are using another serializer, when JobPostSerializer receives nested data, it will take the field work_location and serialize it using whatever he finds defined for that field inside the body of the serializer, which in this case is the WorkLocationSerializer, so actually if any data for the work location is missing, the validation will not pass

Comment: {"work_location":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]}}, got this error when I tried to enter work location without city.